# Jekyll - Create an index of lists ordered by tag

Tags: list, tags, markdown, jekyll

i would like to create an index of lists in jekyll of all tags and the corresponding posts.

My first approach, for-loops for every tag:

```
    <h4>FRUITY</h4>
    {% for post in site.tags.fruity %}  
        <ul class="posts">
            <li>
                <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>        
            </li>
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}

    <h4>SWEET</h4>
    {% for post in site.tags.sweet %}
        <ul class="posts">
            <li>
                <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>        
            </li>
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
    ...
```

This WORKS, but i have to manually create a new for-loop for every new tag.

My second approach, one loop to automatize this step so i dont have to worry about new or removed tags:

```
{% for tag in site.tags %}
  <div class="medium-6 large-3 columns list-view-all">

    <h4>{{ tag | first | upcase}}</h4>
    {% for post in site.posts contains tag %}        
        <ul class="posts">
            <li>
                <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>        
            </li>
        </ul>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>    
{% endfor %}
```

The first part works, every tag becomes a header.
in the inner for-loop ALL posts containing any tag get listed. So the lists for every tag are equal.

**The Question:
How can i make a list for every tag with only the posts corresponding to the respective tag?**

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% for tag in site.tags %}
  <div class="medium-6 large-3 columns list-view-all">

  {% assign currentTag = tag | first %}

    <h4>{{ currentTag | upcase}}</h4>

    {% for post in site.posts %}
      {% if post.tags contains currentTag %}
      <ul class="posts">
        <li>
            <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

  </div>
{% endfor %}
```